# Displaying ReadExisting() in WPF Label

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to display the incoming value from my Arduino into my WPF Label. But it seems the value won't be rendered in my WPF, when i tried to print it in Console Application they had the value. Can u figure it what mistakes that i made?

My XAML Label :

```
<Border Style="{StaticResource borderMain}"
            Grid.Row="7"
            Grid.RowSpan="2"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="4">
        <Label  x:Name="raw_data_label"
                Content="Nothing to Display"
                Style="{StaticResource fontMain}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Border>
```

My C# Code :

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Configure();

    }
    private void Configure()
    {
        SerialPort mySerialPort = new("COM5")
        {
            BaudRate = 9600,
            Parity = Parity.None,
            StopBits = StopBits.One,
            DataBits = 8,
        };
        mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
        mySerialPort.Open();
        mySerialPort.Close();
    }
    private  void DataReceivedHandler(
                    object sender,
                    SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
        raw_data_label.Content = indata;
    }
```

**Update**
Am i right, how i placed the code in there? because if that's right it's still didn't show anything inside the Label.

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Configure();

    }
    private void Configure()
    {
        /*Port port*/
        SerialPort mySerialPort = new("COM5")
        {
            BaudRate = 9600,
            Parity = Parity.None,
            StopBits = StopBits.One,
            DataBits = 8,
        };
        mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
        mySerialPort.Open();
        mySerialPort.Close();
    }
    private  void DataReceivedHandler(
                    object sender,
                    SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
        raw_data_label.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            raw_data_label.Content = indata;
        });
    }
```

Comment: why do you closing the serial port immediately, after open?

Comment: @MansurKurtov yeah i realized that thing too, previously i used `Console.ReadKey()` but it's not working in WPF Application and i was trying to find the replacer for `Console.ReadKey()`. Do you think the problem is coming from that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SerialPort` works on another thread, not main UI thread. so you need invoke to display to UI.

Try replace `raw_data_label.Content = indata;` with:

```
raw_data_label.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
    raw_data_label.Content = indata; 
});
```

---

You must also not close the SerialPort in Configure. Remove this line

```
mySerialPort.Close();
```

Make mySerialPort a private member of the MainWindow class and call `Close()` in a `Closed` event handler of the Window:

```
private readonly SerialPort mySerialPort;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    mySerialPort = new("COM5")
    {
        BaudRate = 9600,
        Parity = Parity.None,
        StopBits = StopBits.One,
        DataBits = 8,
    };

    mySerialPort.DataReceived += DataReceivedHandler;
    mySerialPort.Open();
}

private void DataReceivedHandler(
    object sender,
    SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string indata = mySerialPort.ReadExisting();

    raw_data_label.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => raw_data_label.Content = indata);
}

private void WindowClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mySerialPort.Close();
}
```

Attach the Closed event handler in XAML:

```
<Window ... Closed="WindowClosed">
```

Comment: sorry for asking this, i'm a newcomer on WPF. Where do i put this code? and how to use the `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke` ? Can u explain to me, please.

Comment: Better use `raw_data_label.Dispatcher`. It returns the same Dispatcher instance, but avoids the dependency on the Application class.

Comment: @LeiYang please kindly to check my updated post. am i right doing like that?

Comment: @Clemens i also tried with your code too, but it still didn't show anything. I updated my post incase u want to recheck my code again.

Comment: @Wavesolid Did you debug your application to see whether the DataReceivedHandler is ever called at all? There is `mySerialPort.Close();` directly after `mySerialPort.Open();` which seems wrong.

Comment: @Clemens you right, i did mistake when i try to closing the port. i tried with `Thread.Sleep(5000)` and comment'd the `mySerialPort.Close()` the code runs well. Do you have any idea, how to find a replacer for `Console.Readkey()` in between Open and Close the Port? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Clemens just one new warnings appears. it said "mySerialPort is never assigned". Actually, i'm not sure with this one. if i comment'd the variable `mySerialPort` it gave me the error in the main, but when i opened it again, the same warning showed up. But everything goes fine. can u explain to me, why i need to declare the `mySerialPort` as global variable? Thanks again

Comment: @Wavesolid It is not a global variable, but a member variable (a field) of the MainWindow class. It needs to be that in order to be accessible from the Closed event handler. Be aware that there is `mySerialPort = ...` in the constructor, not `SerialPort mySerialPort = ...` which would assign a local variable.